# WPF DragDrop.GiveFeedback not firing continously

Tags: c#, wpf, events, drag-and-drop, popup

I'm trying to create a popup that follows the mouse pointer while dragging a draggable item.

The following snipping opens the popup at the mouse pointer but I rely on the `GiveFeedback` delegate to allow me to update the popup location (that is, if the pointer moved)

```
private void Members_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    dragPopup.DataContext = DraggedItem;
    var mousePoint = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
    dragPopup.HorizontalOffset = mousePoint.X + this.Left + 10;
    dragPopup.VerticalOffset = mousePoint.Y + this.Top + 10;
    dragPopup.IsOpen = true;
}

private void Members_GiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    if (dragPopup.IsOpen)
    {
        var mousePoint = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
        dragPopup.HorizontalOffset = mousePoint.X + this.Left + 10;
        dragPopup.VerticalOffset = mousePoint.Y + this.Top + 10;
        dragPopup.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

And the popup itself which resided in the main grid of my window.

**NOTE**

I've tried handling the position during the `MouseMove` or `PreviewMouseMove`, but these events are ignored completely during a drag-and-drop procedure.

```
<Popup x:Name="dragPopup" Placement="MousePoint">
    <Border BorderThickness="2" Background="White" DataContext="{Binding}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4,3,8,3">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="8,0,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

The `GiveFeedback` delegate fires only once (setting a breakpoint with a hitcounter of 5 confirms this). Even though [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdrop.givefeedback.aspx) says:

> This event is raised continuously during the drag-and-drop operation. Therefore, you should avoid resource-intensive tasks in the event handler. For example, use a cached cursor instead of creating a new cursor each time the GiveFeedback event is raised.

Why is the delegate fired only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, GiveFeedBack is the way to do it.I did manage to get the GiveFeedBack to be called during drag. Apparently the mouse position in GiveFeedBack is handled different than in the mouse move. I manage to fix this by using the WinForms mouse position. Add reference System.Windows.Forms and System.Drawing for the following code:
Xaml:

```
      <Grid GiveFeedback="Members_GiveFeedback">
                <Popup x:Name="dragPopup" Placement="MousePoint">
                    <Border BorderThickness="2" Background="White" DataContext="{Binding}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4,3,8,3">
                            <TextBlock Text="Test" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="8,0,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ListBox x:Name="sourcList" Height="50"
                    PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                    PreviewMouseMove="sourcList_PreviewMouseMove"
                    AllowDrop="True" >
                        <ListBoxItem > source Item #1</ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>

                <ListBox x:Name="droplist" Height="50" AllowDrop="True" Drop="droplist_Drop" >
                        <ListBoxItem >dest Item #2</ListBoxItem>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>

    private void ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
                var mousePoint = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
                startPoint=mousePoint;

                var point = GetMousePositionWindowsForms();
                var formsmousePoint = new Point(point.X, point.Y);
                var pointfromscreen = dragPopup.PointFromScreen(formsmousePoint);
                dragPopup.HorizontalOffset = pointfromscreen.X - 100;
                dragPopup.VerticalOffset = pointfromscreen.Y - 100;
                dragPopup.IsOpen = true;
            }

            private void sourcList_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
          ...                 
        }

  private void droplist_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {

           ...

        }

    private void Members_GiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dragPopup.IsOpen)
            {
                var point=GetMousePositionWindowsForms();
                var mousePoint = new Point(point.X, point.Y);
                var pointfromscreen=dragPopup.PointFromScreen(mousePoint);
                dragPopup.HorizontalOffset = pointfromscreen.X-100;
                dragPopup.VerticalOffset = pointfromscreen.Y-100;
            }
        }

        public static Point GetMousePositionWindowsForms()
        {
            System.Drawing.Point point = System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition;
            return new Point(point.X, point.Y);
        }
```

Comment: That's it, with a little tweaking I got it set up the way I wanted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just got your popup following my mouse by doing the following:

```
private void ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var mousePoint = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
    dragPopup.HorizontalOffset = mousePoint.X + this.Left + 10;
    dragPopup.VerticalOffset = mousePoint.Y + this.Top + 10;
    dragPopup.IsOpen = true;
}

private void Grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var mousePoint = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
    dragPopup.HorizontalOffset = mousePoint.X + this.Left + 10;
    dragPopup.VerticalOffset = mousePoint.Y + this.Top + 10;     
}
```

Then on the xaml side

```
<Grid MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove">
    ...
    <ListBox Height="50" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" AllowDrop="True">
        <ListBoxItem> ListBox Item #1</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

The position is a little off though.

Comment: The position should be off by 10 because of the  + 10 in `mousePoint.X + this.Left + 10`, is that what you're seeing? I'll give this a try

Comment: Too bad. `MouseMove` isn't fired after a `DoDragDrop` has been initiated. Apparently dragging doesn't qualify as a moving mouse. The popup doesn't follow the mouse and just stays wherever you left it when you start dragging.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void UIElement_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        StartMousePosition = new System.Windows.Point(GetMousePositionWindowsForms().X, GetMousePositionWindowsForms().Y);

        MoveDragInformationPopup();
        DragInstrong textformationPopup.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void UIElement_GiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DragInformationPopup.IsOpen)
        {
            MoveDragInformationPopup();
        }
    }

    private void MoveDragInformationPopup()
    {
        var point = GetMousePositionWindowsForms();
        DragInformationPopup.HorizontalOffset = (point.X - StartMousePosition.X) + 5;
        DragInformationPopup.VerticalOffset = (point.Y - StartMousePosition.Y) + 5;
    }

    private System.Drawing.Point GetMousePositionWindowsForms()
    {
        return System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition;
    }
```